# What's the error in following function code of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I've written one jQuery function to get the city and state code based upon the zip code value but facing some issue with some errors. Can someone please help me in correcting the mistakes I'm making here.

Following is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#zip_code").keyup(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var module_url = $('#module_url').val();

        if (el.val().length === 5) {
            $.ajax({
                url : module_url,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'get_test_category_list','zip_code =' + el.val()},
                success: function(result, success) {
                    $("#city").val(result.city);
                    $("#state_code").val(result.state);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are u getting error in console?

Comment: Please be specific about the errors you're getting.

Comment: @SundarRajan:Not checked in firebug console yet but in editor I'm getting red marks.

Comment: @user2839497 u have to show the error you are getting  then only u will get the correct answer

Comment: Just try `data: {request_type:'ajax', op:'get_test_category_list',zip_code: el.val()}`. I think you probably had un-necessary quotes and an `=` sign there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `data` object, you have invalid syntax. Change this:

```
'zip_code =' + el.val()
```

To this:

```
'zip_code': el.val()
```

The full object should look something like this:

```
data: {
    'request_type': 'ajax', 
    'op': 'get_test_category_list',
    'zip_code': el.val() 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with data part of the ajax
Change it like this

```
data: {request_type:"ajax", op:"get_test_category_list",zip_code : el.val()},
```